# stop jquery append removing line breaks

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-10

I have a div that looks like this

```
<div id='wrap'></div>
```

I want to .append()

```
<input value="a&#10;b">
```

but the value gets altered to

```
"ab"
```

after the append. It seems to be doing this in IE only. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how are you appending it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not only in IE. `&#10;` - newline character in ASCII. If you want multiline field, try to use `<textarea>`. Otherwise you can use zero width space:

```
<input value="a&&#8203#10;b">
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zpbez6t1/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

```
$("#wrap").append("<input/>").find('input').val($('<div>').html('a&amp;#10;b').text());
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xepwucff/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can try this alternatively:

```
$("#wrap").append("<input/>").find("input").val("a&#10;b");
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5bLe6kyw/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the newline to actually be a newline, use a `textarea` instead

```
$('#wrap').append($('<textarea>a&#10;b</textarea>'));
```

But if you want the input to show `a&#10b` you need to escape the ampersand with `&#38;` or `&amp;`

```
$('#wrap').append($('<input value="a&amp;#10;b">'));
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msybs9g7/27/)